# Changing Inline Editing Wrapping Tag per field?

Tags: experience-manager, templating

To enable a component template for inline editing we add the `Enable inline editing for content` Template Building Block and optionally set the `Default field HTML Tag`, which defaults to `<span>`.

We also add the appropriate markup to the Output. For example, I understand we can use `RenderComponentPresentation` or `RenderComponentField` (in DWT), `tcdl:` tags, `tridion:` controls (Java) / tags (.NET), or output the inline editing JSON Markup directly.

**I'd like to choose these fields based on the schema field or how its presented.**

Is there a tag, parameter, setting, or configuration that lets me change the wrapping per field?

**Background**: I mainly want to choose between a span for inline HTML tags and a div for block-level elements to make XPM borders wrap correctly. For now, I'll try adjusting Staging-specific styles and maybe add an XPM-specific class as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Building Blocks that ship with Experience Manager will allow you to choose a single tag that is used for each field, so they are of no use to you.

When I found I needed more fine-grained control over the exact HTML, I decided to write some simple [DWT function sources that **only** output the HTML comments that Experience Manager requires](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/TridionUI2012FunctionsForUseInHtmlTemplates). By using these you'll have full control over your HTML, without having to worry about the exact syntax of the XPM command language too much.

```html
<div class="ContentFull">
    @@MarkComponentPresentation()@@
    <h1>@@MarkComponentField('Title')@@@@Component.Fields.Title@@</h1>
    <div>@@MarkComponentField('Image')@@<img src="@@Image.ID@@"/></div>
    <div class="FullDescription">
        <div class="FullDescriptionText">
            @@MarkComponentField('Description')@@@@Component.Fields.Description@@
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

The function sources and their documentation can be found here: https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/TridionUI2012FunctionsForUseInHtmlTemplates

Comment: +1 and accepted. Much appreciated, Frank. I submitted an SDL Tridion Idea for this level of control and will reference the Tridion Practice wiki.